# Separate multiple events in logstash input into separate documents in elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

INPUT in logstash :

```
{
"Teacher": {
"Name": "Mary",
"age": 20,

},
"Student": [
{
"Name": "Tim",
"age"12

},
{
  "Name": "Eric",
  "age":13

}
]
}
```

Need to filter this input using logstash to send three separate documents into ElasticSearch.

```
doc1: {
"Name": "ABC",
"age": 20,

}
doc2: {
"Name": "Tim",
"age"12

}
doc 3:
{
"Name": "Eric",
"age":13

}
```

Tried split, mutate, ruby filters function but did not get the desired result. Could someone help me separate these into separate outputs to the elasticsearch index.

Comment: The split filter should be the right one.  Can you post the config you tried and describe what happened?

Comment: input {
codec=> json
}

filter{
split{
field => ["Student"]
 }
}

this gives me two documents one with Mary,Tim and another with Mary, Eric but I want the document with Mary as a seperate document too. How can I split the root level input in logstash instead of just the students?

Comment: Clone it first.  Delete the 'Students' array from the clone, which would leave you just Mary.  Split the clone to get Tim and Eric.

Comment: Thank you @AlainCollins .It worked. I got the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want a separate event for 'Mary', use the `clone` filter to create two events.  Delete the 'Students' array from one copy to just be left with 'Mary'.

In the second clone, using the `split` filter will give you different events for 'Tim' and 'Eric'.